# App Force Closes after I Changed Package Name

Tags: android, eclipse

When I created my app, I didn't notice that I misspelled my app name.

My app name was `com.xxx.currencycalculater`, and I changed it to `com.xxx.currencycalculator` in the following places:

Package in `AndroidManifest.xml`,

first line `package` of `MainActivity.java`,

line 10 `tools:context="com.currencycal.gaofanlin.MainActivity"` of `activity_main.xml`.

After these changes, everything was broken, so I right-clicked on src/build path/remove from build path and saved all my files, then restarted eclipse. I tried running it in an emulator, but it crashed.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What about logs, stack trace ?

Comment: Post the logcat output, also be sure to do a full search for the old package name and see if you missed a spot. For example, a layout might be referencing the full app package name.

Comment: After I replace all the "e" to "o" again, and run the app, it works! I think I must missed some spots, thanks @michaelcarrano and all!